# "Sequence contains no elements" Error .Net Core 5

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, postman

There are 2 ids in my database. Both of them avaible in my database. But one of them works normally and the other gives a **"Sequence contains no elements"** error.

```
SELECT * FROM Company
where Id ='08db1da9-6bcx' or Id ='08db3387-12as';
```

This sql gets two of my company. Also "`{{base_web_url}}/company/008db1da9-6bcx`" this GET Method works fine but "`{{base_web_url}}/company/08db3387-12as`" gives **Sequence contains no elements** error.

Here is my code that I've trouble:

```
var company = await this.mainDbContext.Company
      .Where(x => x.Id == id)
      .Include(x => x.Employees)
      .ThenInclude(x => x.Phones)
      .Include(x => x.Employees)
      .ThenInclude(x => x.Emails)
      .Include(x => x.Logo)
      .ProjectToType<CompanyModel>()
      .FirstOrDefaultAsync()
      .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: Don't use `x` for every lambda. Use first letter of the structure name. Now it's really hard to see to what table does `x.Phones` belong to. My guess is that Mapster tries to cast something to a list or enumerable, but it's actually empty. Things like this are the reason I suggest people to stop using mappers altogether. Can you show us the `CompanyModel` and rest of the data structures?

Comment: Does database contain data for the ID.  Use database tool to query database like with SQL Server use SSMS and perform query to determine if there is data.

Comment: Your code does not seem to throw this error. This error normally is thrown when you use Single(), First(), Last() etc. methods rather than SingleOrDefault(), FirstOrDefault(), LastOrDefault() etc. Please double check the *actual* error source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error -
The error is based on you accessing the "this.mainDbContext.Company" collection by using Linq.

When you go ".Where(x => x.Id == id)" it's actually
".Where(company => company.Id == id)"

Culprit-
The issue is that the "this.mainDbContext.Company" collection is empty so what it's actually doing is

".Where(x => empty == id)" so the compiler goes
well you have asked me to check where but it can't be a where since the collection you have provided is empty hence the "Sequence contains no elements"

-Solution
If the process should be stopping due to an error while executing you need to sort how you are getting the data flowing in if not as the process needs to silently handle it and continue then you need to handle that or stick a '?'after "this.mainDbContext.Company".